# Custom directive is not recognized in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I created a custom directive and added it in the declaration of my app.module. But when I use it in my component, it gives me an error of:

> Property binding hasClaim not used by any directive on an embedded
> template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and
> all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng

This is how I created the directive:

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SecurityService } from './security.service';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: '[hasClaim]'
})
export class HasClaimDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private ss: SecurityService,
  ) { }

  @Input() set hasClaim(claimType: any) {
    debugger;
    if (this.ss.hasClaim(claimType)) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I implement it:

```
 <ul class="nav">
      <ng-container *ngIf="securityObject.isAuthenticated">
        <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}}">
            <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]" *hasClaim="'Admin'"> <=== THIS IS THE DIRECTIVE
                <i class="nc-icon {{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!securityObject.isAuthenticated">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="">
          <a routerLink="/login">
          <i class="nc-icon nc-key-25"></i>
          <p>Login</p>
        </a>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="securityObject.isAuthenticated">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="" (click)="logout()">
          <a routerLink="/login">
          <i class="nc-icon nc-lock-circle-open"></i>
          <p>Logout</p>
        </a>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you're declaring the directive in `app.module.ts`, and you want to use in a component declared in `navBarModule.module.ts`

If you **only use the directive** in navbar.component, declare the directive in the NavBarModule.module

Else, you can create a module, e.g. `utils.module`where you declare and export the directive and import in the modules where you has components that need the directive

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HasClaimDirective} from './hasclaim.directive'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [ HasClaimDirective ],
  exports:[HasClaimDirective]
})
export class UtilsModule { }
```

And in nav-module

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,UtilsModule ],
  declarations: [ NavBarComponent ],
  exports:[NavBarComponent ]
})
export class NavBarModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch the error message carefully :

Property binding hasClaim not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".ng

**Possible fix 1:**

see this line what they said :

```
directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations
```

fix is : go to your **app.module.ts**, then import your directive and add it to declaration array after importing

For example: this is in my project

I have imported representatives here.

[image]

I guess your error is trying to say you that - import your directive then put it in declaration array of  `app.module.ts`

**Possible fix 2:**

You shouldn't use star mark (*) before your directive in your html

as angular [doc](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) suggested, read this one doc page may meet your need

[image]